# bitcoin stuck with no confirmations

Tags: blockchain.info

I'm quite new to this. I have transferred coins to a wallet 4 hours ago and I'm still stuck with no confirmations. I do have a Bitcoin wallet on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info). I transferred from Bitcoin market website straight to another wallet if mine and now its stuck. How can I reverse it or get it moving again? I have tried looking for the trusted peer option and all that, but can't get my head around it. This is my block number on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info): a8abd5243ac486822577208f87e46f6864baeb1250c1434b3a1811a017ce6e2f

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I think your question would be a lot more readable if you would use punctuation, proper capitalization, and generally proofread for spelling and clarity. There is an "edit" button right below the post that you can use to make changes.

Answer (score 3):

This transaction is unlikely to be confirmed for a long time.

- It has very low priority because it is spending an output which is unconfirmed. None of the parents of this transaction are confirmed either, going back 5 generations.
- Each transaction in the chain pays a very low fee of around 0.00000259 BTC, which is below the recommended amount and below what other people are paying to get into a block.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a rule of thumb always pay a fees of 0.0001 or more and you will never have slow confirmations. The amount is just 3 cents and shouldn't be decreased .